# Holding variable in struct

Tags: c, struct

I have a HIGHLY performance critical section in my code where i need to minimize cpu load as much as i can. If i have a struct that has one instance, is there ANY difference in performance between defining variables in code by iteself like this:

```
    int something;
    int randomVariable;
```

or defining them in struct?

```
struct Test
{
    int something;
    int randomVariable;
}
```

because i want to use struct to make code look better

Comment: Using 2 `int` prevents any *type-conversion* from taking place, but many compilers will optimize to that result anyway.

Comment: This depends on context.  What is the code [snippet] that you want to optimize?  If you're interested in performance, I assume you've disassembled the compiler output and have built infrastructure to be able to benchmark the code with [nanosecond] resolution--yes?

Comment: Speed, size, code maintenance, readability?  Can you say more about what you mean: _minimize cpu load_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion the best way to know this , first write two different programs in C , with struct and without struct and then make them assembly file with using

`gcc -S file.c`

Since i dont know your code , i directly assigned values to them :

```
int main() {
     int something;
     int randomVariable;
     something = 3;
     randomVariable = 3;
    return 0;}
```

and

```
main() {
struct Test
{
    int something;
    int randomVariable;
}test;
test.something = 3;
test.randomVariable = 3;
return 0;}
```

and i get assembly files on my Ubuntu-64bit , intel i5 machine

I saw that assembly files are nearly same

```
.file   "test1.c"
.text
.globl  main
.type   main, @function
main:
.LFB0:
.cfi_startproc
pushq   %rbp
.cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
.cfi_offset 6, -16
movq    %rsp, %rbp
.cfi_def_cfa_register 6
movl    $3, -8(%rbp) **Second one(with struct) has value -16 instead -8**
movl    $3, -4(%rbp) **Second one has value -12 instead of -4**
movl    $0, %eax
popq    %rbp
.cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
ret
.cfi_endproc
.LFE0:
.size   main, .-main
.ident  "GCC: (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04) 4.8.4"
.section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

So according to that results I can say that two implementation has not any significant difference about CPU load. Only difference between them second one is using very very little more memory than first one.

Answer (score 1):

First, to be fair, *because i want to use struct to make code look better* is purely a style thing.  What looks better to one person may not look better to another.

I am a fan of `struct` when there is a choice, for several reasons.

*Speed/size efficiency*:
Compare a `struct` over over two discrete `int` variables when data needed to be passed as a function argument.

Using:

```
int a;
int b;
```

Or

```
typedef struct {
  int a;
  int b;
}VAR;
VAR var;
```

The same data could be passed as separate pointers via function arguments (assuming 32 bit addressing):

```
int func1(int *a, int *b);//two 32 bit addresses passed
```

Or:

```
int func2(VAR *v);//one 32 bit address passed
```

The efficiency (of this type) goes up directly as number of variable goes up.
(*efficiency gain if there were 100 ints?*)

In the first example, you are passing two `int *`, while in the second, only one.  Its a small difference, but it is a difference.  The magnitude of the advantage is also dependent on addressing used.  32bit or 64bit.

*Code maintenance and readability*:
function prototypes, when used as application programming interface (*[API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_programming_interface)*) should be stable.  Using `struct` as arguments or as a return type support this interface stability.

*For example*: Given a requirement to calculate the changing velocity in *[Cartesian coordinates](http://electron9.phys.utk.edu/vectors/3dcoordinates.htm)* of x, y & z, of an object moving in a straight line with respect to time, you might design a function that would be called repeatedly with current values of velocity<sub>xyz</sub> and acceleration<sub>xyz</sub> and time<sub>ms</sub>.  The number of arguments required clearly suggest use of a `struct`.  Struct is also suggested as the return type:

```
typedef struct {
    double x;
    double y;
    double z;
}VEL; //velocity

typedef struct {
    double x;
    double y;
    double z;
}ACC; //acceleration

typedef struct {
    VEL vel;
    ACC acc;
    time_t ms;
}KIN; //kinematics

KIN * GetVelocity(KIN *newV);
```

If a new requirement for knowing Position<sub>xyz</sub> was added to the project, all that would have to be added is a new member of the KIN struct:

```
typedef struct {
    double x;
    double y;
    double z;
}POS; //position
...
typedef struct {
    POS pos;
    VEL vel;
    ACC acc;
    time_t ms;
}KIN; //kinematics

KIN * GetVelocity(KIN *newV);//prototype will continue to work 
                             //without changing interface (argument list)
KIN * GetPosition(KIN *newV);//new prototype for position also supported
```

Comment: 1) It is desirable for a library's *interface* to stay the same. If you keep the same prototype, but actually take a completely different `struct` and do different stuff with the new information you get, you haven't kept your interface the same at all, you've completely changed it. 2) Wrapping up a bunch of disconnected variables in a `struct` so you can pass them to a bunch of unrelated functions, most of which won't use most of the variables, is one of the worst ideas I've heard.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths - Regarding 1), in my original post (edited, but you can review the edits) I advocated keeping the argument list the same.  I said nothing about using a _completely different struct_.  I explained how using a _modified_ struct (by adding members) could be done without breaking function prototypes.  Regarding 2), I never said _unrelated_ or _disconnected_, but I agree, the variable list and function prototype examples I used in the original answer did not suggest any continuity of purpose.  I have edited the answer.